# Bitcoin types of onion address

Tags: ip-address, address, bitcoin

I'm running a *bitcoin core* full node with Tor and I've configured a hidden service for that.
 The point is: bitcoin core log shows me an onion address which is very smaller than the one I found in `/var/lib/tor/bitcoin-service/hostname`. I noticed that other peers in the network connect with me using the small *.onion* address. Which is the difference between these two types of onion address? Are they correlated eachother in some way? I've also tried to use the longer . onion address in the *externalip* option inside `bitcoin.conf`, but it gave me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shorter `.onion` address is an older, less secure method of identifying the service, which uses a SHA1 hash of the 1024 bit RSA key associated with the service.  The longer address is a newer format, which is the entire public ed25519 key associated with the service.  Some consumers of onion services don't support the newer format, which is probably why you got an error when you used it in `bitcoin.conf`.

Comment: Indeed I read somewhere that bitcoin core doesn't support the newer version.